# how to handpick rows from a pandas dataframe and load to another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe A

[image: dataframe A]

i want to handpick only few rows and load to B dataframe

[image: dataframe B (result)]

how to achieve this using pandas dataframe?

Comment: Do you want random sample or is there any specific filter

Comment: what rule are you using to identify which rows should be filtered/loaded?

Comment: based on column 1 row names

Answer (score 0):

You can try concatenating the dataframes with a proper mask of indexes filtering the rows you want.

```
mask = [2, 3, 6]
B = pd.concat([B, A[mask])
```

Where 2, 3 and 6 are the handpicked indexes. Or, if you want to create a rule,

```
mask = A['column1'] > 0.5
B = pd.concat([B, A[mask])
```